# Unwanted Bolding added to font in browsers

Tags: css, fonts

I have been using HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold font in a project. This is a font included in iOS. When this is displayed in Chrome, Safari and Firefox I am getting an unnecessary bolding or double font effect for some reason.

Today I came across a way to kinda fix it, but wasn't sure if it was a bug in font rendering?

My example below shows the font with no opacity, opacity set at .9999999 (which makes the font look normal) and opacity set with 8 digits (which makes it look like the original double bolded.)

```
.noOpacity {
    opacity:1;
}
.opacity7digits {
    opacity: .9999999;
}
.opacity8digits {
    opacity: .99999999;
}
```

[image]

[image]

I am stumped to why this is happening and any insight would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/J75gW/4/

Comment: It would be helpful to include a screenshot of the problem, since this issue is OS specific (at least, it doesn't appear to happen on Ubuntu) (edit: misread your first paragraph)

Comment: @KelvinMackay I made an edit and added a screen shot of what I see in the jsfiddle

Comment: Ah, looks like antialiasing is your problem. Have a read of http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/26/css-properties-that-affect-type-rendering/ and, since you specifically mention iOS, pay particular attention to webkit-font-smoothing

Comment: Different browsers render fonts differently. For instance, firefox makes most fonts smooth and Chrome (webkit) sharp. It's a browser issue.

Comment: @andrewk I have to disagree guys. I added a animated gif above and only some of the text changes with I add the opacity to the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSX renders subpixel antialiased text a lot heavier than other platforms.  This is particularly true of light-colored fonts on a dark background.  Since you have white text on a black background, you're pretty much seeing this effect at its most extreme.

Is this a bug?  I don't think so, it's just a crappy implementation of subpixel font rendering by Apple.  It's just a guess, but I don't think they've ever fully gotten on board with subpixel rendering:

- They never used it on their mobile devices, even on the low-DPI non-retina iPhones/iPods/iPads - that's why you don't see this effect in iOS.
- They also don't (or didn't - haven't checked this with Mountain Lion) enable subpixel antialiasing in OSX on non-Apple external monitors - you have to run a command in the terminal to enable it.  Presumably this could be because a very, very small number of LCD monitors don't have the red-green-blue subpixel order, which would mess up subpixel rendering.
- All of apple.com has *-webkit-font-smoothing* set to *antialiased*.

## Opacity vs. -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased

The reason that changing the opacity to .9999 (or anything other than 1) makes the fonts thinner is because non-opaque text is generally rendered with simple antialiasing, NOT subpixel antialiasing.  You can get the same effect by using *-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased* (in the browsers that support it).

Want some proof?  Check out this extreme close-up of your original screenshot.  Note the lack of colored fringing around the .9999999 text - that's a sign that the text is not using sub pixel antialiasing.

[image]

Anyway, I think you should either live with the ultra-heavy text on OSX browsers or use *-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased* (and accept that Firefox will not render exactly the same).  The opacity thing is a hack and could very well stop working in the future.