# Font rendering differently on all OS X browsers

Tags: macos, google-chrome, css, safari, webkit

I'm developing this website where I use CSS to style my menu buttons.

They all look good on Windows, but when I try them out on OS X, they render erroneously. What's even more odd is that they show good on a page, but [in my opinion] not so good on another:

Fonts render with a blur around:
[image: Fonts render with a blur around]

Fonts render in "skinny" mode:
[image: Fonts render in "skinny" mode]

Also, I found out that if I hover over an element (ie. logo) that has CSS3 transitions applied on hovering, the **blurry** rendered fonts become rendered **skinny**, but when the CSS3 Animation ends, they resume the **blurry** rendering.

The CSS transitions in cause:

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.logo:hover {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  

    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg) scale(1);  /* FF3.5+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg) scale(1);  /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg) scale(1);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    transform: rotate(-3deg) scale(1);  

    zoom: 1;
}
```

You can observe this phenomenon live here: http://pote.ca.

Help? Please?
Thanks in advance! :)

**UPDATE:**

I am using `verdana` for the menu items, and another font for the *// bun venit* message.

Another example of fonts rendered that do not look good is the menu on Google's Analytics page:

[image]

Comment: Your "don't look good" is entirely subjective. You're simply *used to* Windows' font rendering. Personally I think Windows' fonts look terrible and OS X's look good. Neither way is "correct" or "better". If anything, OS X is arguably "more right" since it preserves the original shape of the letters better.

Comment: I do understand your point, but I just can't warp my mind around how the "R" or the "g" in "Reporting" (last image in the question) is correctly rendered... If somebody can make me believe that this is what the designer intended in the first place, I'd gladly accept your argument as valid. But it's kind of unprobable, at least from my point of view...

Comment: Funny how this is starting to sound as "it's not a bug, it's a feature..." :)

Comment: Well, to say it's a bug you'd first need to prove why one is more correct than the other. As I'm saying, currently we're still at the he said/she said stage of subjective dislikes. :P I'm not arguing that there may *not* be something wrong in Apple's way of doing things, but it is what it is, it's workable, I like it (or at least don't dislike it), and I have yet to see conclusive proof that Windows does an objectively better job.

Comment: We might actually Apple-ishly conclude that my mid-2012 MBP i7 non-retina is just "not good enough" and I just *need* the retina model to enjoy something I thought I had already paid for...

Comment: Now you're just trolling, right? :P

Comment: Not trolling 100%, because the concept also happens to be valid... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not rendered "badly", it uses an overall different font rendering strategy than Windows. OS X tends to preserve the original shape of the character better, while Windows attempts to shove characters into a pixel grid. The results look *different*, not "worse". And yes, you need to take this into account as part of your design.

For reference, see [A Closer Look At Font Rendering](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/), [Coding Horror: What's Wrong With Apple's Font Rendering?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html) etc.

Comment: Cool, but why does it correct itself when the CSS animation is occuring? If it can correct itself then, it means I can correct it once and for all...

Comment: That's anti-aliasing turned off during animations for optimization. You can *try* to disable it, but it's not guaranteed to have an effect and it may also be a jarring experience for users, since they're used to text being rendered a certain way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260431/unwanted-bolding-added-to-font-in-browsers.